# How to update message status to read simply by clicking on friend's profile

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database

I'm facing difficulties in converting messages status read (default value=0/unread, I want it to convert value=1/read).

I have a table for messages with the row "status=0" by default, I want if a receiver opens the message it must be converted to "status=1" Which means that the message has been read. It'll be very helpful if this issue will be solved by onclick() function (any ajax/jquery functions)

[image: Screenshot Attached]

queried friends on sidebar (in message page) coded:

```
<a href="inbox?msgid=<?php echo $id;?>">
   <div class="row con_cont_list">
       <div class="col-3">
           <img src="media/<?php echo $ProfileImg;?>" width="60px" height="60px" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="col-9">
           <p><?php echo $FullName;?>
             <?php if($frnd_msgs_noti):?>
            <span class="badge badge-danger" style="border-radius:50%;"><?php echo $frnd_msgs_noti;?></span>
            <?php endif;?>
          </p>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: onClick() funtion

Comment: is it possible by session method?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a onclick: `<a onclick="changeStatusToRead($id)" href="inbox?msgid=<?php echo $id;?>">`

Setup a route on server that would find the message by id and update its value to 1

Then is JavaScript send the ID to the server:

```
   changeStatusToRead = function (messageID) {
    fetch('set-message-status-to-read', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            messageID
        })
    })
}
```

From this JS code you will receive the `messageID` of the current message in the server side and then do the logic there. After you have updated the message value, send the response from server and expand this JS function into something like this:

```
   changeStatusToRead = function (messageID) {
    fetch('set-message-status-to-read', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            messageID
        })
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
        // data that you have sent from serverside
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how I can connect this with database?

Comment: is it possible by the session method? actually it is just for notifications, I want if the receiver clicks on the sender profile, the notification must disappear after the receiver reads the message.